# How do I make this page format to landscape?

Tags: javascript, printing, format, jspdf, html2canvas

Java to HTML is printing in landscape but is formatted in portrait. I'm using `jsPDF` and `html2canvas`. For some reason the page is printing in landscape but it still formatting the page as portrait.

This is my code.

```js
    const button = document.getElementById('jsPdf');

    function generatePDF() {
        
        // Choose the element that your content will be rendered to.
        const element = document.getElementById('generatePdf');
        window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;

        var doc = new jsPDF({
            orientation: 'landscape',
            unit:'in',
            format: [612,792]
        });

        // Source HTMLElement or a string containing HTML.

        doc.html(element, {
            callback: function (doc) {
                // Save the PDF
                doc.save('sample-document.pdf');
            },
            autoPaging: 'text',
            x: 5,
            y: 5,
            width: 250, //target width in the PDF document
            windowWidth: 1200 //window width in CSS pixels
```

Is there any reason why it wouldn't be switching to landscape in the [print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytF3m.png)? In the picture the page is landscape but the text on it is still formatted in portrait mode as you can see by the smushed text. It's also grabbing the invisible characters.

I tried to make a page print landscape. It turned the page into landscape in the print screen but did not format the actual page to landscape. I am a beginner.